# sql: Writing a fraction in SELECT (stored proc)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SELECT statement as follows:

```
select car.car_ID,isnull(#tmpCount.RowCounter,0) AS RowCounter,ISNULL(#tmpNotServiced.DistinctCounter,0) AS DistinctCounter, ISNULL(#tmpNA.NACounter,0) AS NACounter, (isnull(#tmpCount.RowCounter,0) + ISNULL(#tmpNotServiced.DistinctCounter,0) + ISNULL(#tmpNA.NACounter,0)) AS Total, (CASE ISNULL(#tmpNotServiced.DistinctCounter,0) WHEN 0 THEN 'Closed' ELSE 'Open' END) AS Status
from car
left outer join #tmpCount
on car.AUD_ID = #tmpCount.car_ID
left outer join #tmpNotServiced
on car.AUD_ID = #tmpNotServiced.car_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tmpNA
ON car.car_ID = #tmpNA.car_ID
```

Then a stored proc [p_GetServiced] that counts all open and all closed.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetServiced] 

   AS
    BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #tmp1 
(
    car_ID BIGINT,
    RowCounter BIGINT,
    DistinctCounter BIGINT,
    NACounter BIGINT,
    Total BIGINT,
    [Status] VARCHAR(MAX)
)
CREATE TABLE #tmp2 (car_ServiceDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #tmp1
EXEC [p_GetServiceDetail]

 SELECT [Status] AS [Serviced], COUNT(*) AS [Status] FROM #tmp1
 GROUP BY [Status]


INSERT INTO #tmp2
SELECT car_TargetDate FROM dbo.car
END
GO
```

I want to make it return 'Serviced' and a fraction (2 of 5) eg:Serviced (2 OF 5) OR NotServiced (3 of 5)

*NOTE*: 2 being the open and 5 the total rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you two rows with two columns, one for closed and one for open statuses and the output being in the format that you wanted.

```
SELECT '[OPEN]', 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp1 WHERE [Status] = 'OPEN')) + 
' of ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), COUNT(*)) 
FROM   #tmp1
UNION
SELECT '[CLOSED]', 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp1 WHERE [Status] = 'CLOSED')) + 
' of ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), COUNT(*)) 
FROM  #tmp1
```

Comment: Great answer, just Asking: so it was basicaly concatination with a count?

Comment: @inzefinite It was a concatenation of a sub query count with the overall count of the table. It could be much neater if I pulled out the `COUNT` function results to separate variables, then concatenate them later.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO #tmp1
EXEC [p_GetServiceDetail]

DECLARE @TotalRows BIGINT
SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(*) FROM #tmp1

SELECT [Status] AS [Serviced], COUNT(*) AS [Status], @TotalRows AS [Rows]
FROM #tmp1
GROUP BY [Status]
```

Or, having re-read your question, I think a more satisfying method would be to make use of the `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Status 
+ ' (' 
+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY status)) 
+ ' OF ' 
+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, count(*) OVER ()) 
+ ')' 
FROM #tmp1
```

This yields the following:

```
Serviced (1 OF 4)
NotServiced (3 OF 4)
```

Comment: FYI - while researching this answer I discovered that the default length for `VARCHAR` in a `CAST` or `CONVERT` function is 30.  This is documented in [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)